# When using sheets as floating- tooltip is getting hidden tableau

Tags: tooltip, tableau-api

I am creating a dashboard with multiple sheets, they are of same size. Sheets are added one by one by floating.

Issue: Only to the top most sheet tooltip is getting shown. For all the below sheets, tooltip doesn't get shown.

Answer (score 0):

This primarily happens when the sheet on the top has no data, however still acts as an empty container. Due to this, you can look through the transparent container and it seems that the second sheet is on the top.

However, you still have a top empty container on the top, and the sheet beneath it, visible but intangible.

I have stumbled upon this issue in the past, and [this](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-sheet-selector-for-dashboard) tutorial was really helpful in creating a visualization you plan to.

Basically, you can drag the Vertical layout container to the dashboard. Then, drag each sheet to the dashboard. this will put all the sheets, one atop other vertically.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Manish,I already tried dragging sheets vertically.The problem here is when there are multiple sheets- say 6 there comes empty spaces while toggling to different sheets, and that looks bad. If it's just one or two sheets- the space difference is not much visible, but as the number of dragged in sheets increase, the difference is visually very noticeable. To avoid that I bought in Floating sheets- so that I can give all sheets the same size, but the problem I face here is that only the top most sheet will have the tooltip.

Comment: @JicksyJohn, Floating Sheets ain't gonna help at all. I have implemented this solution with 3 sheets and the end user seems to be pretty unaware of the space issue you said, :D May be you can try distributing your sheets into seperate dashboards and then publish them as Tabs,

Comment: For three sheets- end user won't notice the difference. The problem is, now I have 6 sheets that needs to be shown in a single dashboard and hence it's clearly visible for end user.